# String should have the same value but that's not the case

Tags: string, shell, unix, loops, zsh

Hi there I am trying to read several line of a few files in the folder "posts" a html file in the folder posts could look like this:

```
<h1>stackoverflow</h1>
<h3>14.12.11</h3>

Blbalbla some text here.
```

This is the Code so far...

```
cd posts
for f in *
do
    aname=$(echo "$f" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/')
    headline="<h1><a href="\"#$aname\"">$(sed -n 1p $f)</a></h1>"
    postdate="<h3>$(sed -n 2p $f)</h3>"
    article="$headline $postdate $(sed -n '4,$p' $f)"
    echo "$article"
done
cd ..
echo "$article"
```

The problem basicly is that the first echo in line 8 is not showing the same content as the echo in the last line...but the too strings should have the same value/I want the string to have the same value in the last line as it was in line 8...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For posterity:* This answer didn't exactly solve the original poster's question, there must have been some environmental issues at work.

> Because `article` is only defined within the `for` loop, it is undefined after `done`…
>
> You could just throw a line of: `article=` (nothing after `=`) before the start of the `for` loop to bring the variable outside of the scope.
>
> Basically, anything "created" inside of the loop, only lasts until the loop exits.
>
> ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scoping for more than you want to know about lexical scoping and friends. )

In the interests of future readers who might have a similar issue:

**→** This is **incorrect** in `bash`, `do/done` doesn't create a lexical scope unless `()` are used. However, it appears to be **correct** for some versions or settings for `zsh` (per the follow-up comments from the original poster); but on Fedora 15's default config of `zsh`, it follows the behaviour below, as does `bash` (the scope is not nested without the `()`)

```
for x in 1 2 3; do
    n="$x foo"
    echo -n "$n,"
done
echo "($n)"
```

→ `1 foo,2 foo,3 foo,(3 foo)`

```
for x in 1 2 3; do (
    n="$x foo"
    echo -n "$n,"
); done
echo "($n)"
```

→ `1 foo,2 foo,3 foo,()`

I *don't know* what might have actually caused the problem that prompted this problem, just glad it went away …

Comment: Thorwing a line of article= before the start of the for loop has absolutly no effect...

Comment: Actually, you're right; I was thinking of `()` scopes, and it seems that `do/done` doesn't create a new lexical scope. Unfortunately, with GNU Bash, your example works fine as-is. :-/

Comment: mind if I retag for `zsh`, maybe someone more familiar with it can help; sorry :-(
Running my little test case, above, in zsh, the first example actually does "work for me" if I add an `n=` line to the top of it :-/

Comment: I am just a beginner in Shell scripting, so could you please tell me how to use this with my existing Code? Because either I am doing it wrong or it doesn't work this way too... :S

Comment: It could easily be a difference between shells/OSen/something. Of course, I don't have your `posts/` folder, but just adding `article=` as a line by itself before `for` in the script *seems* like it should work that way :-(

Comment: but when I do it like [this](http://pastie.org/3017199) then it doesn't have any effect...

Comment: Sorry, mate. Works for me; created a test folder with some scratch files (`mkdir posts;for n in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo $n > posts/$n; done`) and I get `<h1>…</h3>` for 1…5, and then 5 again at the end :-(

Comment: Yeah I did something wrong :D It's now working for me too - thx.